# Create a count map

Tags: bash

I have some data with each line representing an id. I want to create a map out of this id. For eg if the file looks like this

```
ID      
12321
14342
12321
34324
345
4564
345
```

the result should be

```
12321 2
14342 1
34321 1
345 2
4564 1
```

The order of the numbers don't matter. I just want the counts.
It's basically the counts. How can I do it in bash?

Comment: Is `34321` a typo in output?

Answer (score 2):

sort and uniq does the job for you,

```
sort file | uniq -c
```

In your case,

```
sed -e '1d' file | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr

while read -r line
do
  k=${arr[$line]:-0}
  ((k++))
  arr[$line]=$k
done < input.txt

for i in "${!arr[@]}"
do
  echo "$i ${arr[$i]}"
done
```

input.txt:

```
12321
14342
12321
34324
345
4564
345
```

Output:

```
14342 1
34324 1
345 2
4564 1
12321 2
```